# How can the files in the NPM and GitHub repositories be different from one another?

Tags: node.js, github, npm, devops, cicd

It appears that the GitHub repo and the NPM repo can have independent contents from one another? What I would like to know is how is this possible, because it would appear to be a security risk? I searched here and online but can't find good answers.  Even the simplest repos can have this disparity.

For example, the simple three file NPM repo named [is-wds-ap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-wds-ap?activeTab=code) shows the three files `README.md`, `index.js`, and `package.json` on the NPM website. You can't get much simpler than that, but if you go to the project's [GitHub site](https://github.com/angelpulido96/package), you will see only ONE file which is the `README.md`.

If you `npm i is-wds-ap`, you will get the THREE files, but if you download straight from GitHub, you get just the ONE. How is this possible? Also, can the NPM and GitHub repos vary by more than just "missing files", as in can the contents be almost entirely different? Which is scary if so and how can we protect ourselves from this other than use the new Beta feature "code" tab on NPM?

Initially, I thought the GitHub repo may have deleted some files without pushing the changes to NPM. But in this example, the GitHub repo only shows a single commit.  Any informative insights into what is going on here would be appreciated.

Comment: From where did you get the idea that NPM and GitHub are **always** in sync, or that they should be? It doesn’t make sense to always push code from a source control repository to a package registry - you’d see a ton of broken packages all the time if that was the case.

Comment: Ask them, instead of asking Stackoverflow (SO is your _last_ resort, not the first). Anyone can trviially delete a github repo and then create a brand new one with the same name after publishing something to npm, with completely different content.

Comment: I never stated that I expected them to be in sync.  In fact I even stated that I thought files had been deleted from the GitHub repo and not synced to NPM, but I noticed that only one commit had occurred on GitHub.  So it would appear that in this example that they NEVER were in sync at any time.  Which is why I have this question.

Comment: @DougC NPM has a way to say "here's where my repo is". There's no deeper Github integration than that involved. They could be entirely different codebases, if someone wanted to be tricksy. Review the code you actually get via a NPM install.

Comment: @ceejayoz - Thank you.  I've installed some things in the past though that **compiled** during the NPM install which is disconcerting if the two repos can have significant differences.  I guess the best solution is to rely on something like snyk.io?

Comment: @DougC `npm install --ignore-scripts`, if you're worried.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to how you need to push code to a Git repository (GitHub) via `git push`, you need to publish npm packages to your registry (NPM) via [`npm publish`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-publish).

NPM will show the `latest` version that was published, and the repository URL comes from the `repository` property in that version's **package.json**.